# how to cross out the text when clicking checkBox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to cross out text next to the checkbox button when the checkbox is clicked by the user. But when I test it, for some reason nothing is happening. I want to check if the box is checked. If it is then I want to to cross that item next to that check box. This function, however does not work. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? thanks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  //button.delete
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = "checkbox"
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement("li")
  newItem.className = "addedClass"

  newItem.appendChild(text)
  if (item === "") {
    alert("please fill in the blanks");
  } else {
    var crap = document.getElementById("todoList")
    crap.appendChild(newItem)
    var addhere = document.getElementById("todoList")
    addhere.appendChild(checkBox);
  }

  function updateItem() {
    if (document.getElementById(checkbox).checked) {
      document.getElementById(todoList).style.textDecoration = "line-through"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="todoForm">
  <input id="todoInput" name="fname" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
</form>
<ol id="todoList"></ol>
```

Comment: You seem to have some quotes missing around the word "todoList" -- it says   document.getElementById(todoList)

Comment: Try to think what takes place when the checkbox is clicked. For now, your code does not seem to handle events. So the first problem you have to solve is this. Also try to use the developer tools (F12) and the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first handle event and call the update function and this snippet for you need to add event to checkbox. i hope it should help you thanks.

```js
function myFunction()
{
 
 var item=document.getElementById("todoInput").value
 var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
 checkBox.type = "checkbox";
 checkBox.id="checkbox"
 checkBox.onchange=updateItem
 var text=document.createTextNode(item)
 var newItem=document.createElement("li")
 newItem.className="addedClass"
 newItem.appendChild(text)
  if (item === "")
  {
    alert("please fill in the blanks"); 
  }
  else
  {
    var crap=document.getElementById("todoList")
    crap.appendChild(newItem)
    var addhere=document.getElementById("todoList")
    addhere.appendChild(checkBox);
   }
   function updateItem()
  {
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("todoList").style.textDecoration="line-through"
    }
  }

}
```

```html
  <html>
    <form  name="myForm" id="todoForm">
    <input id="todoInput" name="fname" required  >
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
       </form>
         <ol id ="todoList">
         </ol>
  </html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it crosses out all the next elements for some reason.  all the other li  are crossed out too

Comment: because you have specified same id to all dynamically generated checkbox checkBox.id="checkbox" your id is same so you need to use different id for different checkbox generated

Comment: so do i just add new class to each checkbox  generated ?

Comment: checkBox.className="new class" and then just style it out in css when its clicked?

Comment: for that you need to many changes like getElementsByClassName()  and specified that better if you used jquery it much easier and less code

Answer (score 0):

you can use other wise HTML5 element for the same purpose.

```
<strike>not yet available!</strike>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lot of issues,

Some of the fixes / improvements I have done,

1. You are missing `}` or closed inappropriately in your code for myFunction().
2. Always try to use `id` for element on which you are going to process. I have added an `id` on `li`. (The text node)

```js
function myFunction()
{

var item=document.getElementById("todoInput").value
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");

 checkBox.type = "checkbox";
 checkBox.id="checkbox"

 var text=document.createTextNode(item)
 var newItem=document.createElement("li")
newItem.id = "textEl";
 newItem.className="addedClass"
 newItem.appendChild(text)
 
  if (item === "") {
    alert("please fill in the blanks"); 
  }
  else{

    var crap=document.getElementById("todoList")
     crap.appendChild(newItem)
    var addhere=document.getElementById("todoList")
     addhere.appendChild(checkBox);
    
    document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      updateItem();
    });
  }
}

function updateItem()
{
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked)
    {
           document.getElementById("textEl").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textEl").innerHTML.strike();
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
   <form  name="myForm" id="todoForm">
     <input id="todoInput" name="fname" required  >
     <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
   </form>
   <ol id ="todoList">

   </ol>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it only seems to  works for the first element in the list. If you click the other elements it wont work for some reason. should i just  use query selector to select all elements ?                                               var list = document.querySelector('li');?